# Impact of the road accelerator on the car's speed in Trackmania Nations Forever

Tags: trackmania-forever

If I enter a road accelerator at speed X KPH in Trackmania Nations Forever, what will be my speed at the end of it? We can assume that my direction is 100% straight.